# Sorting out dates - user input

Tags: java, sorting, date, input

I'm using Java to create an interactive application to ask users for their date of birth. At the minute I have a date being read in and stored as a String in the form (dd-mm-yyyy). Now there are mutliple people being stored in an arraylist, all with different dates of birth. Whats the best way to sort the arraylist depending on their dates of birth?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you storing `Person` objects in the list or dates? If storing dates (`java.util.Date`), you can simply sort the list and it should work out fine for you. If you store `Person` objects, you can pass in a custom `Comparator` which would be used by the sorting utility.

References:

- [Sorting a list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
- [Sorting a list
  based on custom requirements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Hi, I'm storing person objects in the list. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Then just provide in a custom `Comparator` and you should be good to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Start by converting the String to a java.util.Date.  Dates have different semantics for sorting than Strings do.

Once you do that, write a Comparator to do the job for you.  Pass it along with your List to Collections.sort().

Comment: You are correct, thank you.  I've edited my answer.  (Hadn't had any coffee when I wrote it.)

Answer (score 2):

Store the dates in `Date` objects. They are sortable out of the box. Or, if it's sufficient to keep Strings, change the date format from

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

to

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.sort(collection, comparator);

implement your custom comparator (interface `java.util.Comparator`) that compares your object according to date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link already provided in stack over flow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517745/sorting-on-last-name